# selecting latest row of transaction table if row contains some values in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

```
These are my two tables, `Leadid` is Primary Key.


Table1 - (Master)   

    Leadid  Customer Name
    101     Ramesh Kumar
    102     Rajan Kumar
    103     Rahul Kumar

Table2 - (Transaction)

    id  Leadid  Followed_by
    1   101     SAKSHI
    2   101     MADHURI
    3   101     SAKSHI
    4   102     SAKSHI
    5   102     MADHURI
    6   103     SAKSHI
    7   103     SAKSHI

Question : I need all record from `Table1` and `Table2` , in which MAHURI has 
followed latest on Leadid. (As Below)

`102        Rajan Kumar     5   102     MADHURI`


In Case of SAKSHI it Should be:

101     Ramesh Kumar      3     101     SAKSHI
103     Rahul Kumar       7     103     SAKSHI

if same lead id is followed by others, previous transcation should not be included...

i e Leadid 101 was followed by madhuri also but then after followed by SAKSHI. 

so it should not be displayed when putting query for MADHURI.
```

Comment: Can I use same query for SAKSHI also to get result : 

101 Ramesh Kumar 3 101 SAKSHI
103 Rahul Kumar 7 103 SAKSHI

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This QUERY is used for getting latest value for 'MADHURI' only

```
SELECT a.*,b.* FROM `Master` AS a INNER JOIN `Transaction` AS b ON a.Leadid = b.Leadid WHERE Followed_by = "MADHURI" ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

To use for all transction use the query

```
SELECT a.*,b.* FROM `Master` AS a INNER JOIN `Transaction` AS b ON a.Leadid = b.Leadid WHERE b.id = 'userid' ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

change userid according to different users..

Comment: The first part's correct. But the second part is poor.

Comment: Thanks You ! But in case of SAKSHI it shows only one record 103, where It should show 101 also because 101 is last followed by SAKSHI. Please check and Help:

Comment: result is true..because latest one followed by 'sakshi' is 'rahulkumar'

Comment: SAKSHI has Followed Two leads (latest) : 101 and 103

Comment: In your second table a replication of data exists..That is against relational database concept..before starting your project make sure that your tables are normalized..

Comment: To get the above result ...use  (SELECT a.*,b.* FROM `Master` AS a INNER JOIN `Transaction` AS b ON a.Leadid = b.Leadid WHERE Followed_by = "SAKSHI" ORDER BY b.id ASC LIMIT 1)UNION(SELECT a.*,b.* FROM `Master` AS a INNER JOIN `Transaction` AS b ON a.Leadid = b.Leadid WHERE Followed_by = "SAKSHI" ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1);

Comment: Thanks Yes this is what i am looking for , Now only one problem : transaction table  id  for 101 should be 3 the latest transaction of 101 by SaKSHI ...     and for MADHURI same query gives worng result 101 and 102 both http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4fbb/22/0    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4fbb/28/0

Comment: Your requirement doesn't match with each other.actually what do you want??

Comment: OK I want to put a common query for all users either SAKSHI or Madhuri to database and result should be according to User :  if I pass a query for madhuri result should be all lead which is last followed by MADHURI.... Please reads Question again and help me.

Comment: (Select Master.*, Transaction.* from Master left join Transaction on Transaction.Leadid = Master.Leadid where Followed_by = "SAKSHI" order by Transaction.Leadid asc limit 1)UNION
(Select Master.*, Transaction.* from Master left join Transaction on Transaction.Leadid = Master.Leadid where Followed_by = "SAKSHI" order by Transaction.Leadid desc limit 1):    IT works for sakshi but not for Madhuri

Answer (score 0):

```
// SAME CODE WHILE SELECT FOR SAKSHI


SELECT s.*,t.* FROM master s
INNER JOIN Transaction t
ON(t.leadid = s.leadid)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Transaction tt
             WHERE t.leadid = tt.leadid
               AND t.id < tt.id)
 AND t.followed_by = 'SAKSHI'



// SAME CODE WHILE SELECT FOR MADHURI


SELECT s.*,t.* FROM master s
INNER JOIN Transaction t
ON(t.leadid = s.leadid)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Transaction tt
             WHERE t.leadid = tt.leadid
               AND t.id < tt.id)
 AND t.followed_by = 'MADHURI'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4fbb/39/0

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4fbb/38/0

Answer (score -1):

select leadid,customername,id,leadid,followedby from master a , transaction b where a.leadid= b.leadid and followedby = 'MADHURI' order by leadid desc

Comment: Can I use same query for SAKSHI also to get result : 

101 Ramesh Kumar 3 101 SAKSHI
103 Rahul Kumar 7 103 SAKSHI

Comment: @ranjan Kumar   -- yes you can !!

Answer (score -2):

```
Select Master.*, Transaction.* from Master left join Transaction on Transaction.Leadid = Master.Leadid where Followed_by = "MADHURI" order by Transaction.Leadid desc limit 1
```

Comment: Can I use same query for SAKSHI also to get result : 

101 Ramesh Kumar 3 101 SAKSHI
103 Rahul Kumar 7 103 SAKSHI

Comment: Thanks You ! But in case of SAKSHI it shows only one record 103, where It should show 101 also because 101 is last followed by SAKSHI. Please check and Help:

Comment: You should put question properly.